# Download only 1 variant of each video file in JDownloader?

Tags: jdownloader

I've grabbed some video links and I want to download only one single variant (360p) of each of the packages. Is there a way to do that, instead manually doing it for each video?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward so long as the site you are downloading from is one of the ~4000 for which custom plugins are available.

Using YouTube and 360p as an example:

1. Open JDownloader 2 **settings**.
2. Navigate to the **plugins** page.
3. Select **Youtube** or the site you wish to set properties for.
4. Under **Allowed Media Types**,
   select the **Image/Video Resolution** drop down menu and select 360p.

[image: Picture]

Detail:
[image: Detail]

Note: The plugins vary from author to author,
so the choices will vary from plugin to plugin,
but YouTube has many customization options.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these methods will work, but if you have already  started downloading multiple videos, editing link grabber wont help: here's a quick workaround; first, place your cursor on downloads tab, press control A, mark all files, press and hold control key while left clicking on one of the plus signs (this should drop down all folders) then go to the bottom screen; you'll find a search box to find files jdownloader is handling, type one of the other existing formats you don't want: e.g (m4a) it should highlight everything that contains that file type, move cursor back to the downloads tab, left click on any of the files, press control A again then right click on any of the highlighted files: this should bring out some options, next, select disable, there you go.. it should stop downloading that file type now. Repeat for others file types as  needed and leave only the file type you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using filtering is the most effective way you can do what you ask.

In **settings**, there is a "**Linkgrabber Filter**" on the left side(way below General; Reconnect;etc..) and it is a filter out, so if you need only something specific you need to negate your target search.

***For Example:***

If you need only audio files that are of specific audio type **opus** then use **File Type** --> **is not** (as you want to negate the filter **out** part and make it filter **in only** your specific target) --> **Custom Type** (as from the drop-down the **Audio** means all audio types).

Then, before you confirm, you can use the test field at the bottom as you insert your link and click the play button (▶️) on the left side of the input field in order to test your filter.

Finaly hit save.

**REMEMBER:** **All filters saved are active all the time, UNLESS** you make them *(manually)* inactive by removing the marker for the specific filter you wish to not apply for the following "link grabbing process" in the **Linkgrabber Filter** section of the **Settings**

**NOW**, after you filtered the content, move to the **LinkGrabber** panel and select all (links and named packages with keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+a**) then use the right mouse button, then under the section denoting the source - let's say you link-grab from *FunCatVideos* - it will open another submenu when you hover and there you can choose to modify the existing variant or add another. **There** you can specify that 360p you want your videos to be downloaded as. So now, all your links are filtered and the variant of the video/audio is specified for all of them and you can start downloading.

P.S. I hope that helps. Functional for JDownloader versions as of Jan 2023 Build, forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Select all video by pressing Ctrl+A, right click>youtube.com>change variant for # link/s>Choose your desired quality>Press select.